# What exactly is the python interpreter implemented with?

Tags: java, python, c

I am a beginner in programming, and trying to learn Python from "Learning Python by Mark Lutz". In the 'Introducing the Python Interpreter' chapter the author states the following:

> Depending on which flavor of Python you run, the interpreter itself may be implemented as a C program, a set of Java classes, or something else.

I am unable to understand how a piece of Python code is distinguished for a division to be made in the interpreter (either C program or Java classes as the author states).

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by your last sentence? I can't quite tell what aspect you're confused about.

Comment: This means that if you have a code in python, there is another piece of code (which is written is C or Java or whatever), which looks at it and translates into programming instructions for your computer. That is what is called interpreter - otherwise python code would merely be as useful as a text file.

Comment: I guess the author of *Learning Python* trying to say is "there are more than one Python interpreters, one of them is implemented with C, another with Java, yet another with something else."

Comment: The interpreter doesn't look at your code and then decide whether to be implemented in C or Java. If you have CPython (which you probably do), it's implemented in C. Jython is implemented in Java. Other implementations are written in whatever they're written in.

Answer (score 8):

A piece of Python code, is just Python code. What the author is saying is that there are different Python interpreters - all of which do run Python code . these different Python interpreters can be programs written in [C](http://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html), in [Java](http://www.jython.org/), in [C#](http://ironpython.net/), or in  [Python](http://www.pypy.org/) itself. They are the program that is run when you  type `python` at the command line, or pick `python` from an application menu. Ordinarily it will be CPython: the reference implementation of the language made by the Python Software foundation, which is written in C.

All in all, this is definitely non-essential for learning Python - just skip ahead, and come back to this issue once you are more familiarized with the Language.

Answer (score 3):

The reference interpreter of Python, the one that the others use as a guide, is written in C, and it is nicknamed CPython (not to be confused with Cython, which isn't an interpreter). It compiles Python code to Python bytecode and runs it on its virtual machine, which is also written in C.

There are other interpreters. Here are a few that are most well-known.

- [Jython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jython), written in Java, which compiles Python to Java bytecode, and runs it on the Java Virtual Machine. It allows Python code to call Java code. Somehow.
- [IronPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IronPython), written in C# (some of which is apparently written BY Python), which compiles Python to Microsoft's CLI (correct me if I'm wrong) bytecode, and runs it on the corresponding virtual machine.
- [PyPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyPy), written in RPython (a stricter branch of Python), which compiles Python to PyPy bytecode (mostly the same as CPython bytecode) and runs it on its virtual machine. More info: http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/interpreter.html

Theoretically and ideally, all strictly-legal Python code should run the same on any of these. Think of it like different compilers for C: strictly-legal C code will compile to equivalent programs on any of the compilers

- Some non-standard things will be allowed by one compiler, but not another (`void main()` in Visual Studio is non-standard).
- A compiler for Linux won't have access to the `windows.h` library (like CPython won't have access to the Java libraries).
- They will have different speed/memory performance for different tasks.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your true question is how a Python interpreter does what it does.  This is the subject of entire college-level courses, but here is the thrust.

The interpreter reads the Python source with a specialized function called a parser. This is an input processor that understands the exact structure of the Python language in the form of a *context free grammar*.

The parsing procedure checks the input for compliance with Python syntax rules (here is where syntax errors originate) and produces a data structure that has distilled the raw meaning of the Python program in the form of very simple steps represented in a simple array of bytes called byte code.

The complete process of input, parsing, and byte code production is called compilation. Yes, at its heart, Python has a simple kind of compiler.

Byte codes do very basic things like arithmetic, testing and jumping to other byte code locations based on test results, string operations, calling and returning from functions, input, output, and all the hundreds of fundamental operations that Python programs perform that, when combined and executed quickly, make programs seem powerful.

Where the original Python source was reasonably close to human language (well, sort of...), the byte code is reasonably close to machine language: the patterns of 1's and zeros that processors understand as instructions.  Byte code is what's written to `.pyc` files when a program runs.

It takes only a quite small and simple program (and hopefully a fast one) called the byte code interpreter (yes an interpreter within the Python interpreter) to process the byte code in order to have the processor do the work that the original Python program intended.

Of course if a `.pyc` file already exists and is newer than the corresponding source code, the compilation can be skipped.

There you have it... A college course in a few sentences. I have skipped enormous amounts of detail, and (a caveat) some of what I've written applies only to some of the many Python implementations out there, but it's a start at understanding.

The author of your book is saying that the implementation language of all above might be C or Java (the Jython implementation of Python). He left out that only a minimal core of Python is implemented in C or Java.  The rest is in Python itself.

If you're interested in knowing more, there are some reasonably good, low-cost and free sources.  See for example [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10115/Crafting-an-interpreter-Part-1-Parsing-and-Grammar) and also for not too much money try [Scheme 9 From Empty Space](http://www.lulu.com/shop/nils-m-holm/scheme-9-from-empty-space/ebook/product-17363264.html) for how an interpreter of a language other than Python is implemented.